# Repositioning UIPopoverController on device rotation

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios7, swift, uipopovercontroller

I'm trying to re-position a popover view when the device is rotated. I use this code to create the popover:

```
        settingsViewCtrl = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("settingsViewCtrl") as SettingsViewCtrl;
        settingsPopoverCtrl = UIPopoverController(contentViewController: settingsViewCtrl);
        settingsPopoverCtrl.delegate = self;
        let m:CGFloat = min(view.frame.width, view.frame.height);
        let s:CGSize = CGSizeMake(m - 100, m - 100);
        let r:CGRect = CGRectMake(view.frame.width * 0.5, view.frame.height * 0.5, 1, 1);
        settingsPopoverCtrl.setPopoverContentSize(s, animated: true);
        settingsPopoverCtrl.presentPopoverFromRect(r, inView: view, permittedArrowDirections: nil, animated: true);
```

And I use `willRepositionPopoverToRect` in my delegate ...

```
func popoverController(popoverController:UIPopoverController!, willRepositionPopoverToRect rect:UnsafeMutablePointer<CGRect>, inView view:AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<UIView?>)
{
    if (settingsPopoverCtrl != nil && settingsViewCtrl != nil)
    {
        let r:CGRect = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.width * 0.5, self.view.frame.height * 0.5, 1, 1);
        settingsPopoverCtrl.presentPopoverFromRect(r, inView: self.view, permittedArrowDirections: nil, animated: true);
    }
}
```

But that can't be it since when I rotate the device I'm getting the warning:
**Application tried to represent an active popover presentation:** 
and the popover also isn't repositioned.

How do I get to apply and update positioning CGRect in willRepositionPopoverToRect so that the popover view updates? Would it be possible to modify the provided `rect:UnsafeMutablePointer<CGRect>` and give it back to the popover?

---

**UPDATE:**

According to the docs (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverControllerDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIPopoverControllerDelegate/popoverController%3awillRepositionPopoverToRect%3ainView%3a):

> If you want to propose a different rectangle for the popover, put the
>   new value in this parameter.

So the question is: How do I put the new value into this rect?

Answer (score 5):

Let me answer this:

```
        let r:CGRect = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.width * 0.5, self.view.frame.height * 0.5, 1, 1);
        rect.initialize(r);
```

... will obviously init the given rect with new dimensions and it works flawless when changing device rotation, unlike the misleading code on Apple's docs where they tell to use `presentPopoverFromRect` once again, which totally doesn't work.